# elastic sorting results with wildcards occurrences. amount of "*find*" terms

Tags: sorting, elasticsearch, wildcard

i have nasty problem with elastic result sorting combined with boolean type of query (a kind of wildcard).

lets say we have blog post with field "content".
each post contains some info about dragons. with all combination of that words "dragonians.. drago. minidragon.". alot of text.

and we need to searching it, by string `"*rago*"`.

idealy that means that we need to match all documents, that contains all that combination for `*rago*`

im using simple_query before

"query_string": {
"default_field": "content",
"query": `"*rago*"`
}

im satisfied with result. but sorting... is not taking into account amount of occurrences.
sorting are ignoring how many times that `"*rago*"` was occured in content field of each document.

how to solve that?

i spent few days on googling... term vectors.. field data. scripts etc. but anyway nothing seems related to the problem.
sorting works with match query for example, but then i need to search for "dragon" not for `"*rago*"`

but for suggestion search we using > we need to be able to search by any part of input string.

will really appreciate any kind of help.

Answer (score 0):

### Wildcard queries get rewritten to `constant_score` queries by default

This means that the match score elasticsearch calculates for ranking will disregard `term frequency` (the number of occurrences of a query term in the searched field).

Also, elasticsearch is not matching `"*rago*"`, but rather the unique list of indexed terms (across all blog posts in your case) which match the wildcard expression:

`Pseudocode: MATCH ANY_OF("dragon", "dragonians", "minidragon", "drago", ...)`

If you want a blog post which uses `"dragon"` twice to outrank a blog post which uses `"minidragon"` once (for the query `"*rago*"`), then add the parameter `"rewrite": "scoring_boolean"` to your query.

See the caveats and other rewrite options here: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-multi-term-rewrite.html